# onMessage android Webview React Native not working in physical device (ios and virtual android working!)

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, webview, react-native

My webview contain (embed, code, ...) so because i used onMessage and injectedJavascript, i'm try console event in onMessage in ios and vitual android returns results, only physical android not return result, please let me keyword and why?? Thank you very much!

```
<WebView
    {...otherProps}
    javaScriptEnable={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
    source={{ html: templates[this.props.template]({html, fontSizeContent, fontSizeContentPre, highlightThemes, enableNightMode}) }}
    onLoad={this.onLoad.bind(this)}
    injectedJavaScript={this.injectedJavaScript()}
    onMessage={this.onMessage.bind(this)}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    style={{
            height: Math.max(realContentHeight, minHeight), 
            backgroundColor: enableNightMode ? COLORS.COLOR_NIGHT_MODE : COLORS.COLOR_UN_NIGHT_MODE
          }}
    />
```

---

```
hackBefore() {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
    `
        (function(){
            var originalPostMessage = window.postMessage;
            var patchedPostMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer) {
                originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
            };
            patchedPostMessage.toString = function() {
                return String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace('hasOwnProperty', 'postMessage');
            };
            window.postMessage = patchedPostMessage; `
    :
    `
        if (window.postMessage.length !== 1) {
            window.postMessage = function(msg) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                window.postMessage(msg);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    `
}

hackAfter() {
    return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '})();' : ''
}
```

---

```
injectedJavaScript() {
    return ` 
        ${this.hackBefore()}
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

        if (!Element.prototype.matches)
        Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;

        if (!Element.prototype.closest)
        Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
            var el = this;
            if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
            do {
                if (el.matches(s)) return el;
                el = el.parentElement || el.parentNode;
            } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1); 
            return null;
        };

        function dispatchAction(action, params) {
            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                action,
                params,
            }));
        };


        ${this.hackAfter()}
    `
};
```

---

```
onMessage(event) {
    console.log('event', event)
    const { action, params } = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);

    console.log('action', action)
    console.log('params', params)

    switch (action) {
    case 'heightCaculated': {
        return this.setState({
            realContentHeight: params.height,
            isRendering: false,
        });
    };
    case 'addImages': {
        this.props.resetImages();
        params.imgs.map(img => Image.prefetch(img));
        return this.props.addImages(params.imgs);
    };
    case 'openGallery': {
        return navigator.navigate('Gallery', {
            index: params.index,
        })
    };
    default:
        return null;
    };
};
```

Comment: please help me!!

Comment: I'm also stuck in this thing please help @longnk

Comment: @Codesingh you can read my solution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24143, this solution woking if you use react native < v0.59, use WebView in react-native, good luck :D

Comment: Thanks man but i'm using react native 0.60.0